# When to use dsgesv versus dgesv to solve a system of linear equations

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix, precision, lapack

In the LAPACK documentation, it states that DSGESV (or ZCGESV for complex numbers) is:

> The dsgesv and zcgesv are mixed precision iterative refinement
>   subroutines for exploiting fast single precision hardware. They first
>   attempt to factorize the matrix in single precision (dsgesv) or single
>   complex precision (zcgesv) and use this factorization within an
>   iterative refinement procedure to produce a solution with double
>   precision (dsgesv) / double complex precision (zcgesv) normwise
>   backward error quality (see below). If the approach fails, the method
>   switches to a double precision or double complex precision
>   factorization respectively and computes the solution.
>
> The iterative refinement is not going to be a winning strategy if the
>   ratio single precision performance over double precision performance
>   is too small. A reasonable strategy should take the number of
>   right-hand sides and the size of the matrix into account. This might
>   be done with a call to ilaenv in the future. At present, iterative
>   refinement is implemented.

But how can I know what the ratio of single precision performance over double precision performance is? There is the suggestion to take into account the size of the matrix, but I don't see how exactly the size of the matrix leads to an estimate of this performance ratio.

Would anyone be able to clarify these things?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the best way to go is to test both `dgesv()` and `dsgesv()`...

Looking at the source code of the function [`dsgesv()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d8c/dsgesv_8f_source.html) of Lapack, here is what `dsgesv()` tries to perform:

- Cast the matrix `A` to float `As`
- Call `sgetrf()` : LU factorization, single precision
- Solve the system `As.x=b` using the LU factorization by calling `sgetrs()`
- Compute the double precision residue `r=b-Ax` and solve `As.x'=r` using `sgetrs()` again, add `x=x+x'`.

The last step is repeated until double precision is acheived (30 iterations max). The criteria defining success is:

[image]

where [image] is the precision of double precison floating point numbers (approximately 1e-13) and [image] is the size of the matrix. If it fails, `dsgesv()` resumes to `dgesv()` since it calls `dgetrf()` (factorization) and then `dgetrs()`. Hence `dsgesv()` is a mixed precision algorithm. See [this article](https://eg.sib.uc.pt/bitstream/10316/10052/1/ficheiro.pdf) for instance.

***Lastly, `dsgesv()` is expected to outperform `dgesv()` for small number of right-hand sides and large matrices***, that is when the cost of the factorization `sgetrf()`/`dgetrf()` [image] is much higher than the one of the substitutions `sgetrs()`/`dgetrs()` [image]. Since the maximum number of iteration set in `dsgesv()` is 30, an approximate limit would be

[image]

Moreover, `sgetrf()` must proove significantly faster than `dgetrf()`. `sgetrf()` can be faster due to a limited available memory bandwidth or vector processing (look for SIMD, example from SSE: the instruction `ADDPS`).

The argument `iter` of `dsgesv()` can be tested to check whether the iterative refinement was useful. If it is negative, iterative refinement failed and using `dsgesv()` was just a waste of time !

Here is a C code to compare and time `dgesv()`, `sgesv()`, `dsgesv()`. It can be compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -llapacke -llapack -lblas` Feel free to test your own matrix !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <lapacke.h>

int main(void){

    srand (time(NULL));

    //size of the matrix
    int n=2000;
    // number of right-hand size
    int nb=3;

    int nbrun=1000*100*100/n/n;

    //memory initialization
    double *aaa=malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    if(aaa==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    double *aa=malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    if(aa==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    double *bbb=malloc(n*nb*sizeof(double));
    if(bbb==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    double *x=malloc(n*nb*sizeof(double));
    if(x==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    double *bb=malloc(n*nb*sizeof(double));
    if(bb==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}

    float *aaas=malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
    if(aaas==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    float *aas=malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
    if(aas==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    float *bbbs=malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
    if(bbbs==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    float *bbs=malloc(n*nb*sizeof(float));
    if(bbs==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}

    int *ipiv=malloc(n*nb*sizeof(int));
    if(ipiv==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}

    int i,j;

    //matrix initialization
    double cond=1e3;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(j==i){
                aaa[i*n+j]=pow(cond,(i+1)/(double)n);
            }else{
                aaa[i*n+j]=1.9*(rand()/(double)RAND_MAX-0.5)*pow(cond,(i+1)/(double)n)/(double)n;
                //aaa[i*n+j]=(rand()/(double)RAND_MAX-0.5)/(double)n;
                //aaa[i*n+j]=0;
            }
        }
        bbb[i]=i;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            aaas[i*n+j]=aaa[i*n+j];
        }
        bbbs[i]=bbb[i];
    }

    int k=0;
    int ierr;


    //estimating the condition number of the matrix
    memcpy(aa,aaa,n*n*sizeof(double));
    double anorm;
    double rcond;
    //anorm=LAPACKE_dlange( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'i', n,n, aa, n);
    double work[n];
    anorm=LAPACKE_dlange_work(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'i', n, n, aa, n, work );
    ierr=LAPACKE_dgetrf( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, n,aa, n,ipiv );
    if(ierr<0){LAPACKE_xerbla( "LAPACKE_dgetrf", ierr );}
    ierr=LAPACKE_dgecon(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'i', n,aa, n,anorm,&rcond );
    if(ierr<0){LAPACKE_xerbla( "LAPACKE_dgecon", ierr );}
    printf("condition number is %g\n",anorm,1./rcond);

    //testing dgesv()
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    for(k=0;k<nbrun;k++){

        memcpy(bb,bbb,n*nb*sizeof(double));
        memcpy(aa,aaa,n*n*sizeof(double));



        ierr=LAPACKE_dgesv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,n,nb,aa,n,ipiv,bb,nb);
        if(ierr<0){LAPACKE_xerbla( "LAPACKE_dgesv", ierr );}

    }

    //testing sgesv()
    t = clock() - t;
    printf ("dgesv()x%d took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",nbrun,t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    t = clock();
    for(k=0;k<nbrun;k++){

        memcpy(bbs,bbbs,n*nb*sizeof(float));
        memcpy(aas,aaas,n*n*sizeof(float));



        ierr=LAPACKE_sgesv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,n,nb,aas,n,ipiv,bbs,nb);
        if(ierr<0){LAPACKE_xerbla( "LAPACKE_sgesv", ierr );}

    }

    //testing dsgesv()
    t = clock() - t;
    printf ("sgesv()x%d took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",nbrun,t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    int iter;
    t = clock();
    for(k=0;k<nbrun;k++){

        memcpy(bb,bbb,n*nb*sizeof(double));
        memcpy(aa,aaa,n*n*sizeof(double));


        ierr=LAPACKE_dsgesv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,n,nb,aa,n,ipiv,bb,nb,x,nb,&iter);
        if(ierr<0){LAPACKE_xerbla( "LAPACKE_dsgesv", ierr );}

    }
    t = clock() - t;
    printf ("dsgesv()x%d took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",nbrun,t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    if(iter>0){
        printf("iterative refinement has succeded, %d iterations\n");
    }else{
        printf("iterative refinement has failed due to");
        if(iter==-1){
            printf(" implementation- or machine-specific reasons\n");
        }
        if(iter==-2){
            printf(" overflow in iterations\n");
        }
        if(iter==-3){
            printf(" failure of single precision factorization sgetrf() (ill-conditionned?)\n");
        }
        if(iter==-31){
            printf(" max number of iterations\n");
        }
    }
    free(aaa);
    free(aa);
    free(bbb);
    free(bb);
    free(x);


    free(aaas);
    free(aas);
    free(bbbs);
    free(bbs);

    free(ipiv);

    return 0;
}
```

Output for n=2000:

> condition number is 1475.26
>
> dgesv()x2 took me 5260000 clicks (5.260000 seconds).
>
> sgesv()x2 took me 3560000 clicks (3.560000 seconds).
>
> dsgesv()x2 took me 3790000 clicks (3.790000 seconds).
>
> iterative refinement has succeded, 11 iterations